# Diagonal Wins aren't being detected Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have created a Connect 4 game in Python using pygame. My board is:

```
board = []
for row in range(6):
    board.append([])
    for column in range(7):
        board[row].append(0)
```

Although when I have a diagonal win it doesn't seem to register. Can anyone see the issue with the algorithm to detect a winner. If so could you inform me of what to change?

```
    # check / diagonal spaces
for x in range(7):
    for y in range(6):
        if board[x][y] == 1  and board[x+1][y-1] == 1 and board[x+2][y-2] == 1 and board[x+3][y-3] == 1:
            winner = "Red"
            redpoints = redpoints + 1 
            return True

# check \ diagonal spaces
for x in range(7):
    for y in range(6):
        if board[x][y] == 1 and board[x+1][y+1] == 1 and board[x+2][y+2] == 1 and board[x+3][y+3] == 1:
            winner = "Red"
            redpoints = redpoints + 1 
            return True
```

Comment: Diagonals in the +x, +y direction look fine. But for the +x, -y direction, you are going out of bounds. Use something like [x][y+4], [x+1][y+3], etc.

Comment: You're indexing the board in the wrong order, should be `board[y][x]`. Aren't you getting IndexErrors?

Comment: yeah I am, but rather than solving the index errors, i want to solve the entire detection of diagonal wins hence why I've stated the title the way I have

Comment: The logic behind the code is fine. It should work if you fix the IndexErrors. Though, depending on how you do that, you might need to add checks in the -x/+y and -x/-y directions.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the 6 rows, I assume that these are the y positions, and that the 7 elements you append to each row are the x positions. If this is the case, then your indexing in the code for diagonal win check is the reverse of the indexing when you populate the board. I would agree with Rawing in reversing the indexes. it might also make more sense to place the x loop inside the y loop instead of the other way round, to stay consistent with the way you populated the board.